# Get a item on LocalStorage after login on angular not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, globalstorage

Cheers !

I am trying to retrieve a list stored on localstorage after login in Angular, i am storing the data calling a method inside globalstorage, but i realized that i can't retrieve it right away, after setting the item on localstorage during login process, when i first call it on my datepicker component to a dropdown list, it cames null, it only works after refreshing the page a single time.

i tried:

```
public getStores() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeList'));
  }
```

then calling on the standalone component like this.

```
this.StoreList = this.GlobalStorage.getStores();
```

on html:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">
          <label for="basicSelect">Lojas</label>
          <select
            class="form-control"
            id="basicSelect"
            formControlName="LojaSelecionada"
          >
            <option
              *ngFor="let store of StoreList"
              [value]="store.code"
            >
              {{ store.storename}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

after component renders, nothing shows up and the value cames like a empty array.

After refreshing the page, everything shows up and work as expected, but the refresh is necessary to
it happen.

Can anyone give me a light about what i'm doing wrong? I am considering using NGRX for dispatch these functions for reducers, but i would like to use Localstorage to do this task.

Comment: Why don't you call local storage directly without having to do it through a method? this.StoreList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeList') || '{}')

Comment: And where you call the GlobalStorage.getStores()? In `ngOnInit`?

Comment: I tryed on ngOnInit and inside the constructor, but since constructor is executed before ngOnInit, the output is simply the same. I kind of realized that the problem itself is on the standalone component, the other components are retrieving the data right away without any problems, but the standalone seems to be rendering  before the other components.